# How do you call tall, thick fonts, similar to Bebas?

Tags: fonts, typography, style-identification

I'd like to find similar fonts to Bebas (below):

[image]

What do you call these types of fonts? Thick, tall, and usually all in uppercase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're searching for fonts like that, look for **condensed** fonts. Traditionally used for cramming words into small spaces, they're more often used now for crisp bold blocky titles. [Here's an article about using them well](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/20/condensed-fonts-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/).

Tall font = narrow font, set at a large size.

Sounds like you're looking for condensed [sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) fonts with a fairly heavy [weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Weight).

Most font browsers will let you search on 'condensed' as a search term, and narrow by sans and weight using facets - some, like Typekit, will even let you put in 'Width', including narrow fonts that don't identify as condensed - https://typekit.com/fonts?classification=sans-serif&weight=heavy&width=condensed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they have a particular name.

I would probably call them **Black, Heavy or Extra Bold** fonts.

[Typekit](https://typekit.com) has a nice search tool that lets you browse by style (in this case sans-serif) and weight, among other properties.

Answer (score 3):

Bebas is a "condensed" "sans serif" font. Some font families have condensed versions, meaning that the width of the letters is narrower in the condensed version than in the block or book versions. Serifs are the little flourishes coming out of the character where it sits on the baseline like Times New Roman or Garamond. Sans is french for without, so sans serif simply means without serifs.

As you can see in this example, Helvetica narrow bold closely resembles Bebas:

http://www.glassamerica.com/StockFont/helvetica_condensed_bold.jpg

Helvetica is a sans serif font. So by selecting a condensed and bold version, you adequately replicate BEBAS.

Answer (score 2):

These fonts called "condensed" fonts. You can find some useful alternatives below.

Tungsten: http://www.typography.com/fonts/tungsten/overview/ (best alternative i think.)

Economica: (google font): http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Economica

Tulpen One (google font): http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Tulpen+One

Open Sans Condensed (google font): http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed

Six Caps (google font): http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Six+Caps

Answer (score 1):

Check out

Oswald  https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald
or maybe https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Anton

good luck

Comment: When posting answers to font questions please include a screenshot of the font.

Answer (score 0):

Pathway Gothic One (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Pathway+Gothic+One) is somehow similar to Bebas, but most similar is a free font Bebas Neue from Dafont.com

http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font

Answer (score 0):

I'd use heavy or bold to describe them, I use to use Bebas frequently here's an alternative: [Langdon](https://www.behance.net/gallery/7814505/Langdon)

(I would recommend downloading, opening in illustrator and re proportioning a few things, i.e middle leg on E, to fit your preferences.)

Answer (score -2):

Best options for web are (all google fonts):

Fjalla One

Anton

Francois One

Comment: welcome to gd.SE! We're looking for complete answers with an explanation. The question asks "how do you call this type of font" not "what fonts are similar to this one"